# Changing the color of map polygon (not mouseover)

Tags: d3.js, mapping

Within the data join...I have something like the following which changes the opacity according to the mouseover event.  The opacity is changed for the **current** polygon.

```
.enter().append("path")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
};
```

But I want to change this behaviour....so that all other polygons (i.e. NOT(this) ) have their colour changed. The current polygon keep its current colour and the other polygons will have their opacity changed.

In the context of the USA...if the user hovers over California then the colour for all remaining 49 states would change colour.

Thanks

Comment: `d3.selectAll("path").filter(function(e) { return e != d; }).style("opacity", 1);`

Comment: nyce ! Elegant solution Lars.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to save the selection and use it in the `.on` event:

```
var allPolygon = svg.selectAll('.findme')
    .data(dat)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr('class', 'findme')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        allPolygon.style("opacity", 1);
    };
```

[sample illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/YaMLr/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use D3's `.filter()` to filter the elements in the selection and set attributes accordingly:

```
d3.selectAll("path").filter(function(e) { return e != d; }).style("opacity", 1);
```

This will select all `path`s except the current one and set their opacity to 1.